# Best Codec and Pixel Formats to use in FFMPEG Pipeline

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtsp, codec

I have created an FFMPEG Pipeline to stream video frames to an RTSP server. The frames are RGB frames with 3 dimensions. My pipeline command is as follows:

```
openPipeLine = _popen("ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 30 -video_size 720x1280 -pixel_format bgr24 -i pipe: -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://localHost:8554/mystream", "w");
```

I can barely make out the picture when I connect to the server via VLC Media. The colors seem scrambled. I've attached a sample image and the output on the server.

Are there any recommended Codec's that I can use to solve this? Perhaps the pixel format should be changed. I'm currently using a Codec and pixel format that I found online without knowing if these are the best options.
[original frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtiiZ.jpg)
[server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19og.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Comment: The video size is incorrect. `720x1280` means 720 columns and 1280 rows. The convention for image size (resolution) ordering is horizontal first and vertical second. The resolution of the posted "original image" is close to 1280x720, if that is your intention.

Comment: Hi Rotem, Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. I altered the size and it drastically improved the output. The problem now is that approximately 20% of the left hand size of the original image is cut off and appears on the right hand side in the output. Is this also a size issue? Should I alter the sizes until it comes right? It may be important to note that I write out the output using `fwrite(frame.data, 1, 1280 * 720 * 3, openPipeline)`

Comment: Since you are using `_popen`, I assume you are using Windows. In Windows it's important to open the pipe in binary mode - replace `"w"` with `"wb"`. You should know the exact resolution of the input video without guessing.